# Чем заменить структуру в Swift?

Tags: c++, массивы, swift, структуры

Необходимо написать массив из структур на Swift, опираясь на существующий код на c++.

с++:

```
struct luchnik{
  int sila=0, target;
  float hp=100, udar=0;
};
```

Потом создается массив из структур

```
luchnik a[20];
```

И последующая работа с ним:
Обращение к определенным элементам, их изменение итд.
Как лучше реализовать это на Swift?
Как я понимаю, там не используется похожая схема работы.

Comment: Лучше для начала почитать что-нибудь о языке. Или хотя бы погуглить `swift массивы`, `swift классы`.

Answer (score 2):

Ничего не понял, но все равно попробую:

создать  структуру

```
struct luchik {
    let sila=0
    let target:Int
    let hp = 100
    let udar = 0
}
```

Объявить массив, который может содержать только эти структуры

```
var a = [luchik]()
```

работа с массивом

```
let lu:luchik = luchik(target:1) // создать объект (у target нет значения по дефолту, поэтому надо что то присвоить)

a.append(lu) // добавить в массив

print(a[0].hp) // прочитать из массива значение hp первого элемента
```